# Union of lists in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have such dict : (mails is list of lists with dicts inside)

```
result = {'id': 'no_id',
'mails': [[{'mail1': 'asf2@mail.com'},
{'mail2': 'asf1@mail.com'}],
[{'mail3': 'asf4@mail.com'},
{'mail4': 'asf3@mail.com'}],
[{'mail5': 'asf6@mail.com'},
{'mail6': 'asf5@mail.com'}]]}
```

how can I produce : (mails is a list of dicts)

```
result = {'id': 'no_id',
'mails': [{'mail1': 'asf2@mail.com'},
{'mail2': 'asf1@mail.com'},
{'mail3': 'asf4@mail.com'},
{'mail4': 'asf3@mail.com'},
{'mail5': 'asf6@mail.com'},
{'mail6': 'asf5@mail.com'}]}
```

Will it be good to do this?

```
reduce(lambda x, y: result['mails'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `chain` from `itertools`

example:

```
from itertools import chain

result['mails'] = list(chain.from_iterable(result['mails']))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[]
for i in result['mails']:
    l.extend(i)

result['mails']=l[:]
```

Use `extend` to merge one list to other

in single line :`print reduce(lambda x, y:x+y ,result['mails'])`

given Reduce take two arguments `one function` and `iteratable item` like list

Comment: why reduce and lambda are bad? just interesting